# SharePoint list date column problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm reading date column in one of the list and creating document in another list with same date but strangely dates gets change. For example, Date column value is 4/6/2013 but when setting into another list its changing to 3/6/2013.

Here is how I'm reading the date field from List 1,

```
if (listItem["RDSDate"] != null) { dt = DateTime.Parse((listItem["RDSDate"].ToString())); }
```

Here is how setting in list 2,

```
 lItem["RDSDate"] = dt.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't need to use the ToString() method and then parse it back into DateTime. The field should already be stored as DateTime if it is a date field and as such you just need to cast it as such.

```
if ((DateTime)listItem["RSDate"] != null)
{
    dt = (DateTime)listItem["RSDate"];
}
```

I cast it in the if/else statement so that the cast exception would be thrown sooner. If you just want it to return a null value if it's not a DateTime object (in this case, I don't think you should do this because that really ought to be a DateTime), you can use `if(listItem["RSDate"] as DateTime != null)` instead.

Going back the other way (assigning the dt value to the "RSDate" field without casting) should work, or if it doesn't (the dt.Date is in a format that is incompatible with the RSDate field) it should throw an error, not input invalid data.

As to why you're getting the wrong date in there, it might be that somewhere in SP you've got things set to UK date/time values, which if memory serves is DD/MM/YYYY, not MM/DD/YYYY like the US uses. It doesn't matter when you're passing DateTime objects around, but if you convert them into strings you might get errors.

Comment: Thanks John. Even if I use your suggestion when I read from List 1 date column it reads 3/6/2013 where as actual date is 4/6/2013. That's why it's getting wrong in List2 column. It's strange I never see this problem before.

Comment: Is it consistently a day off? What's the date/time on the SharePoint server?

Comment: Yes for all the docs. Lets say if list item has RDSDate column 04/06/2013, When I read and display it shows 03/06/2013

Comment: Well, if you're sure it's always a day off, one hack would just be to use the `.AddDays(1)` method before running whatever other calculation you need on the field. But that's not a really great long-term answer. Is it returning GMT? Depending on what time of day (I think GMT is 9 hours ahead of PDT, for instance), it could be returning yesterday...

Comment: But I'm not trying Now() where time zone may matters. It's the date saved in the list which I'm trying to read.Does it make any sense to display yesterday date if I created an item today?

Comment: When I'm display date it shows 6/2/2013 12:00:00 AM whereas actual date saved in column is 6/3/2013

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

`if (listItem["RDSDate"] != null) 
{
DateTime dt= Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateDateTimeFromISO8601DateTimeString(listItem["RSDate"].ToString());
}`

and include the below namespace

`using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;`